# Overall count for substrings in a string java

Tags: java, string, twitter, substring

I have a program which takes tweets from twitter which contain a specific word and searchs through each tweet to count the occurrences of another word that relates to the topic (e.g. in this case the main word is cameron and it's searching for tax and panama.) I have it working so it counts for that specific tweet but I can't seem to work out how to get an accumulative count for all the occurrences. I've played around with incrementing a variable when the word occurs but it doesn't seem to work. The code is below, I've taken out my twitter API keys for obvious reasons.

```
public class TwitterWordCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurationBuilder configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        configBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX);
        configBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX);
        configBuilder.setOAuthAccessToken(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX);
        configBuilder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX);

        //create instance of twitter for searching etc.
        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(configBuilder.build());
        Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

        //build query
        Query query = new Query("cameron");

        //number of results pulled each time
        query.setCount(100);

        //set the language of the tweets that we want
        query.setLang("en");

        //Execute the query
        QueryResult result;
        try {
            result = twitter.search(query);

            //Get the results
            List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();

            //Print out the information
            for (Status tweet : tweets) {
                //get information about the tweet
                String userName = tweet.getUser().getName();
                long userId = tweet.getUser().getId();
                Date creationDate = tweet.getCreatedAt();
                String tweetText = tweet.getText();

                //print out the information
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Tweeted by " + userName + "(" + userId + ") on date " + creationDate);
                System.out.println("Tweet: " + tweetText);
                // System.out.println();
                String s = tweetText;
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
                while (matcher.find()) {
                    System.out.print(matcher.group() + " ");

                }

                String str = s;
                String findStr = "tax";
                int lastIndex = 0;
                int count = 0;
                //int countall = 0;

                while (lastIndex != -1) {
                    lastIndex = str.indexOf(findStr, lastIndex);

                    if (lastIndex != -1) {
                        count++;
                        lastIndex += findStr.length();
                        //countall++;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(findStr + " = " + count);

                String two = tweetText;

                String str2 = two;
                String findStr2 = "panama";
                int lastIndex2 = 0;
                int count2 = 0;

                while (lastIndex2 != -1) {
                    lastIndex2 = str2.indexOf(findStr2, lastIndex2);

                    if (lastIndex2 != -1) {
                        count++;
                        lastIndex2 += findStr.length();
                    }

                    System.out.println(findStr2 + " = " + count2);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (TwitterException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm also aware that this definitely isn't the cleanest of programs, it's work in progress!

Comment: So what is the problem your are encountering?

Comment: @Maljam the problem is that I can't get a counter which adds up the accumulated total of words to work

Comment: right, but what is the `int count` showing?

Comment: @Maljam that counts it just for that tweet not for the complete set of tweets

Comment: What `count2` is for? I am not sure you are aware of that: `count2` is never changing. You are incrementing the `count` in your second loop.

Comment: count2 is supposed to do the same as count, just with a different word

Comment: @ReşitDönük I want to find a selection of tweets, in this case 100, which include the word cameron and then from these count how many times the word tax occurs over the whole selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define your count variables outside of the for-loop.

```
int countKeyword1 = 0;
int countKeyword2 = 0;

for (Status tweet : tweets) {

    //increase count variables in you while loops

}

System.out.Println("Keyword1 occurrences : " + countKeyword1 );
System.out.Println("Keyword2 occurrences : " + countKeyword2 );
System.out.Println("All occurrences : " + (countKeyword1 + countKeyword2) );
```